# Serializing a Complex Object for a GET Request for ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, model-binding

So, previously my team used POST requests for everything. I finally won the war in convincing them the use the verbs as intended.
GETs for queries,
POSTs for creates etc.

We have a pretty complex object which we need to send as a GET:

```
{
    "UserId": "1",
    "CategoryId": "39",
    "StartMillis": 1609459200000,
    "EndMillis": 1635724799000,
    "GroupByAttributeTypeId": "105",
    "SelectedAttributes": [{
            "TypeId": "100",
            "AttributeIds": [1]
        }, {
            "TypeId": "105",
            "AttributeIds": [6697]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is easy as a POST, but not so much as a GET. The `Action` method that we created looks something like:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route(AspNet.Mvc.ActionTemplate)]

public IActionResult GetCompletedAudits([FromQuery]CompletedAuditDto payload)
{
   return OkResponse(_auditService.GetCompletedAudit(payload));
}
```

where `CompletedAuditDto` is:

```
public class CompletedAuditDto
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public long StartMillis { get; set; }
    public long EndMillis { get; set; }
    public string GroupByAttributeTypeId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<TypeAttributeDto> SelectedAttributes;
}
```

and `TypeAttributeDto` is:

```
public class TypeAttributeDto
{
    public int TypeId;
    public IEnumerable<int> AttrIds;
}
```

And I've tried many different serializations using the [qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs#stringifying) library.
But the `SelectedAttributes` collection always comes up as null.
I turned my logging down to the `debug` level and the model binder doesn't even seem to attempt to deserialize that object (no mention of the `SelectedAttributes` collection)

> [14:35:44 DBG] Attempting to bind parameter 'payload' of type 'WebApp.Payloads.Request.CompletedAuditDto' ...
> [14:35:44 DBG] Attempting to bind parameter 'payload' of type 'WebApp.Payloads.Request.CompletedAuditDto' using the name '' in request data ...
> [14:35:44 DBG] Attempting to bind property 'WebApp.Payloads.Request.CompletedAuditDto.UserId' of type 'System.Int32' using the name 'UserId' in request data ...
> [14:35:44 DBG] Done attempting to bind property 'WebApp.Payloads.Request.CompletedAuditDto.UserId' of type 'System.Int32'.
> [14:35:44 DBG] Attempting to bind property 'WebApp.Payloads.Request.CompletedAuditDto.CategoryId' of type 'System.String' using the name 'CategoryId' in request data ...
> [14:35:44 DBG] Done attempting to bind property 'WebApp.Payloads.Request.CompletedAuditDto.CategoryId' of type 'System.String'.
> [14:35:44 DBG] Attempting to bind property 'WebApp.Payloads.Request.CompletedAuditDto.StartMillis' of type 'System.Int64' using the name 'StartMillis' in request data ...
> [14:35:44 DBG] Done attempting to bind property 'WebApp.Payloads.Request.CompletedAuditDto.StartMillis' of type 'System.Int64'.
> [14:35:44 DBG] Attempting to bind property 'WebApp.Payloads.Request.CompletedAuditDto.EndMillis' of type 'System.Int64' using the name 'EndMillis' in request data ...
> [14:35:44 DBG] Done attempting to bind property 'WebApp.Payloads.Request.CompletedAuditDto.EndMillis' of type 'System.Int64'.
> [14:35:44 DBG] Attempting to bind property 'WebApp.Payloads.Request.CompletedAuditDto.GroupByAttributeTypeId' of type 'System.String' using the name 'GroupByAttributeTypeId' in request data ...
> [14:35:44 DBG] Done attempting to bind property 'WebApp.Payloads.Request.CompletedAuditDto.GroupByAttributeTypeId' of type 'System.String'.
> [14:35:44 DBG] Done attempting to bind parameter 'payload' of type 'WebApp.Payloads.Request.CompletedAuditDto'.
> [14:35:44 DBG] Done attempting to bind parameter 'payload' of type 'WebApp.Payloads.Request.CompletedAuditDto'.

Any ideas how I can get this serialized into a format which the model-binder would be happy with.
This is one of the many things I have attempted:

> UserId=1&CategoryId=39&StartMillis=1609459200000&EndMillis=1635724799000&GroupByAttributeTypeId=105&SelectedAttributes%5B%5D.TypeId=100&SelectedAttributes%5B%5D.AttributeIds%5B%5D=1&SelectedAttributes%5B%5D.TypeId=105&SelectedAttributes%5B%5D.AttributeIds%5B%5D=6697

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need add getter setter in your model like below:

```
public class CompletedAuditDto
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public long StartMillis { get; set; }
    public long EndMillis { get; set; }
    public string GroupByAttributeTypeId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<TypeAttributeDto> SelectedAttributes { get; set; }
}
public class TypeAttributeDto
{
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> AttrIds { get; set; }
}
```

Then send request like below:

> UserId=1&CategoryId=39&StartMillis=1609459200000&EndMillis=1635724799000&GroupByAttributeTypeId=105&SelectedAttributes[0].TypeId=100&SelectedAttributes[0].AttrIds=1&SelectedAttributes[1].TypeId=105&SelectedAttributes[1].AttrIds=6697

Comment: I can't believe I did not see that. I remember thinking yesterday that something looked amiss, but I could not put my finger on it. I'd never code like that, so I did not consider that public variables were randomly being used instead of properties. But its on me for not seeing it. Thanks very much. The next challenge is finding a serializer which will serialize a Javascript object like that. Thanks again.

Comment: As an addendum, you can serialize it using qs like this: `qs.stringify(val, { allowDots: true })` which results in a string like this `UserId=1&CategoryId=39&StartMillis=1609459200000&EndMillis=1635724799000&GroupByAttributeTypeId=105&SelectedAttributes%5B0%5D.TypeId=100&SelectedAttributes%5B0%5D.AttrIds%5B0%5D=1&SelectedAttributes%5B1%5D.TypeId=105&SelectedAttributes%5B1%5D.AttrIds%5B0%5D=6697` . The model binder was happy with that.